# Rails is not sending custom font to browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fonts

I'm having problems to add custom fonts to a rails app. it doesn't work locally,. At my network tab i can't see my custom font being loaded.

font is stored at: /assets/fonts/Page-icon.ttf

Assets.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf .otf)
```

Application.rb:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"
```

Rails 5.0.0.1

thanks

Comment: Can I see your styles ?

Comment: I'm not worried about styles right now, At the moment i just want to see the fonts being transfered to browser. My application.css.scss doesnt has any import or reuqire to fonts.

Comment: worth a shot: try  *.svg *.eot *.woff *.ttf

Comment: maybe it cat help https://github.com/sorentwo/font-example

Comment: Added the * but didnt work. I cant understand why is not working, its so simple and I have followed all usual steps.

Comment: I've created a cloud9 project to test adding custom fonts https://preview.c9users.io/viniciusdba/fonts/     even in there is not working, I used the github font example. I dont know what else i have to do

Comment: If your styles don’t reference the font, then the browser isn’t going to download it.

Comment: Thanks matt, it worked!

Comment: The font is not loaded from a 2nd level scss. Im creating a font face and using it, but From this 2nd level scss file the browser seems to not recognize the font load. Im using font-src. From the main applications.css.scss the font loads